# How to configure the Bluemix SingleSignOn service from the command line?

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

I created an instance of the SingleSignOn service (SSO) in Bluemix, using

> cf create-service

Now, when I try to deploy an app that uses that service, I get the follwing message:

> CTJSO0015E The service instance with ID \"xxxxxxxxxx\" in the region \"xxxxx\" must be configured before the operation can be performed. If you are attempting to create a new service and bind it to your application in a single step, your service instance should already be created in your dashboard, but you must configure it before binding it to an application. Configure the service and try binding the application again.

I'd like to do an automated deploy of all of this so my only choice is the command line. I know there are many options and I think I'd go with the database (seems to be the simplest possibility).  Google or Facebook login would be ok as well.

How do I configure the service using the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can see the troubleshooting about SSO here: https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#troubleshoot/SingleSignOn/ts_index.html#sso_troubleshooting

in this case:

If you try to bind an application when you create a service instance, the Add Service task fails with the following error message:

> CTJSO0015E The service instance with ID svcinstanceid must be
>   configured  before the operation can be performed.

The Single Sign On service does not support binding an application to an unconfigured service instance. You must complete the service instance creation before you bind an application to it. The service creation succeeds when you leave the application unbound. Then, you have to use UI\dashbord service to configure it.